# Generating organized excel spreadsheet from a word document

Tags: python, openpyxl, python-docx

I have Microsoft document which we want to transfer to excel. Every sentence needs to be separated and then pasted into the next appropriate cell in excel. These sentences also need to be analyzed as a heading, requirement, or informational. 
I will recreate what the typical word format looks like

```
2.3.4     Lightening Transient Response 
          The device shall meet spec 24532. Voltage must resemble figure.
          Figure 1.
```

which translates to

```
<numbering>      <Heading>
                 <Requirements/information>
```

In excel that is almost exactly how I would the document to look except the second requirement sentence should be in row just below the previous requirement sentence.

```
2.3.4   | Lightening Transient Response     | Heading
        | The device shall meet spec 24532. | Requirement
        |Voltage must resemble figure       | Requirement
        |figure  1                          | Informational
```

I have attempted this project with python using openxl and docx modules. I have code that can go into word and get sentences and then code that can analyze the sentence.I'm retrieving runs from paragraphs. I am having problems because not all sentences are coming back due to how the word document is formatted. I am typically only getting the headings back. The heading numbers are not stored in runs. The requirements underneath the headings are stored in tables. I have written some code to get into the tables an extract the text from cells so that is one way to get the requirements however that snippet of code is giving problems(giving me the same sentence three times in a row).

I'm looking for other possible ways to do this. I'm thinking a format switch. XML has been mentioned and then also the pdf and pythons pdf module may be possible.

Any thoughts or advice would be greatly appreciated.

-Chris

Comment: Additionally, there are pictures in the word document which I do not know how to bring into my program and eventually put into excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is going to be harder, not easier. You're closer than you seem to think. I recommend attacking each problem separately until you crack it.

The sentence three times problem in the table is because of merged cells. The way python-docx works on tables, there is an underlying table layout of x rows and y columns. If two side-by-side cells are merged, you get the same results for both those cells. You can detect this be comparing the two cells for equality. Roughly like "if this_cell == last_cell skip this cell".

There's no way around the heading problem. Heading numbers only exist inside a running instance of Word; they are generated at display (or print) time. To get those you need to use the same rules to generate your own numbers. So you'd need to keep track of the number of headings you've passed through etc. and form your own dot-separated numbering.

Comment: Scanny, your advice to stick with it is good to hear. For the table reading I am actually using some code you had put up on someone else's question. I'll post it.

Comment: tables=doc.tables
for table in tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
               print(paragraph.text)

Comment: Scanny, I did this and now have a successful table reader. I basically had to store the last 6 cells and check to make sure that the current cell wasn't the same as any of the last 6 cells. Much thanks ++

Comment: Glad to hear you got that part working. Be sure to use the upvote & accept features to properly indicate a helpful answer and a "correct" one. We work for points around here :) I always find it strange that that works to motivate myself and others to take the time to help, but it does :)

Comment: I'm boosted by similar feedback so I understand. I have another question. So far my programs are reading all the paragraphs and then reading all the tables. Right now the way I can think of to organize it back to the original order would be to manipulate object code <docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph object at 0x030B0E30>. However i think this would be difficult. I would like to read each object in the given order. Say I had: <paragraph> <paragraph> <table> <paragraph> .  I'd like to go through these and call my functions paragraph_read, paragraph_read, table_read, paragraph_read.

Comment: @Chris Sounds like a new question. If you tag it with 'python-docx' I'll see it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Python for this?  Just use VBA, since you are working with Excel and Word.

Something like this should get you pretty close to where you want to be.  It may need some tweaking...

```
Sub Demo()
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Set wdApp = Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument
wdDoc.Range.Copy

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
With ActiveSheet
.Paste Destination:=Range("A" & .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
End With

Set myRange = Range("A1:A100")
For i = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count

    If InStr(myRange.Cells(i, "A").Value, "Voltage") > 0 Then
        myRange.Cells(i, "A").Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        If InStr(myRange.Cells(i, "A").Value, "Voltage") > 0 Then
            position1 = InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, "Voltage")
            myRange.Cells(i + 1, "A").Value = Mid(ActiveCell.Value, position1, 99)
            ActiveCell.Value = Left(ActiveCell.Value, position1 - 2)
            i = i + 2
        End If
    End If

Next i


End Sub
```

So, copy the text from your Word doc, which should be open and active, and you're good to go.  There are other ways to do this too.